# Как сделана автонастройка записей у конструкторов сайтов?

Tags: dns

Всем привет. Есть множество различных конструкторов: wix, tilda и т.д., все они продают домены. Каким образом идет автоматическое добавление различных записей (A, CNAME, NS) для домена? Какой должен быть функционал, чтобы реализовать подобную возможность? Т.е. человек в личном кабинете покупает домен в конструкторе, но какие действия идут внутри конструктора?

Comment: Написать скрипт, который будет формировать файл зоны в формате описанном в, например, rfc1034 и релоадил демона отвечающего за DNS зоны (named или bind, например).

Comment: [общая информация](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5167802/4827341) и [конкретный пример api](https://www.reg.ru/support/help/api2)